# How to retrieve data from database in label

Tags: c#

I wanat to retrieve student ID from database. Here is my code what i have tried but it is not displaying anything.
Thanks...

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-Q69PRF4;Initial Catalog=new;Integrated Security=True");


        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        string str = "select * from StRecords where StID='" + Session["login"] + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Label11.Text = dt.Rows[0]["StID"].ToString();

    }


    }
```

Comment: You are not executing the command try that: SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {}

Comment: @RadinGospodinov `da.Fill(dt);`

Comment: Could you debug your code? Please make sure your `Session["login"]` should have some value.

Comment: Yes it has some value.

Comment: @RadinGospodinov I had also used it but it give an error "Invalid when no data is present" OR ."Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: If it isn't displaying anything, it means that `dt` is empty... possibly due to that nothing is being returned from the database? Maybe you should verify that something is being returned, as a first step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take just `StudentId` from the database, then you just select that column and use `ExecuteScalar` property.

**Code**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-Q69PRF4;Initial Catalog=new;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        string str = "select [StID] from StRecords where StID = @stdId;";
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con))
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stdId", Session["login"]);
            Label11.Text = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Also always use parameters instead passing the value in single quotes to avoid SQL injection attack.

Also try to give the connection string in `Web.Config` file.

Comment: it give an error."Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @hirawaseem in that case there is no value returned - you should debug and check if `Session["login"]` has a valid value and that value also exists in your database